# OpenAPI: Generator name must be specified error when generating using Gradle

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am facing a peculiar issue with OpenAPI

Essentially, I am trying to generate some code, for a rest api/server using OpenAPI

This is what I have so far

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2" }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        // Updated version can be passed via command line arg as -PopenApiGeneratorVersion=VERSION
        classpath "org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:$openApiGeneratorVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.openapi.generator'

openApiMeta {
    generatorName = "Sample"
    packageName = "org.openapitools.example"
    outputFolder = "$buildDir/meta".toString()
}

openApiValidate {
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/petstore-v3.0-invalid.yaml".toString()
    recommend = true
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/petstore-v3.0.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/spring-api".toString()
    apiPackage = "org.openapitools.example.api"
    invokerPackage = "org.openapitools.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "org.openapitools.example.model"
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary: "java8"
    ]
    globalProperties = [
            modelDocs: "false"
    ]
    skipValidateSpec = true
    logToStderr = true
    generateAliasAsModel = false
    // set to true and set environment variable {LANG}_POST_PROCESS_FILE
    // (e.g. SCALA_POST_PROCESS_FILE) to the linter/formatter to be processed.
    // This command will be passed one file at a time for most supported post processors.
    enablePostProcessFile = false
}

task buildJavaResttemplateSdk(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "java"
    library = "resttemplate"
    inputSpec = "$rootDir/petstore-v3.0.yaml".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/java-resttemplate-api-client"
    apiPackage = "com.example.client"
    invokerPackage = "com.example.invoker"
    modelPackage = "com.example.cdm"
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary: "java8"
    ]
    groupId = 'com.example'
    id = 'client'
    skipValidateSpec = true
    logToStderr = true
    generateAliasAsModel = false
    enablePostProcessFile = false
}
}
```

Now the issue I am facing is this

When I run openApiGenerate I get the following error

Cause: Generator name must be specified

When I run the Task buildJavaResttemplateSdk

It runs fine

What is the issue that is causing this, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you haven't given the gradle config correctly. I have added the additional config for open-api in config.json

```
tasks.register("hello", GenerateTask) {
String taskName = hello.name
generatorName = "spring"
inputSpec = "$rootDir/src/main/resources/static/openapi.yaml".toString()
outputDir = "$buildDir/generated-sources/openapi-$taskName".toString()
configFile= "$rootDir/src/main/resources/static/openapiConfig.json".toString() }


compileJava {
dependsOn processResources
dependsOn tasks.hello
source "${openApiGenerate.outputDir}/src/main/java" }


sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDirs += file("${buildDir}/generated-sources/openapi-${hello.name}/src/main/java")

    }
} }
```